# Roeketchat React Native app blank screen issue

Tags: react-native

**Always getting blue blank screen when running the mobile app on the android physical device  without any error logs.
**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEcRs.jpg)

**#Environment  ---------------------**

```
    OS : Windows 10 Pro
    Rocket.Chat App Version : 4.41.0
    Android Device Name/OS : Galaxy S10/Android 12, Galaxy S22+/Android 13

    node : 18.18.1
    jdk : 17.0.9
    gradle : 7.0.4
    yarn : 1.22.19
    react-native : 11.3.7
```

**#build Settings  -------------**

```
    buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 23
    compileSdkVersion = 33
    targetSdkVersion = 33
    glideVersion = "4.11.0"
    kotlin_version = "1.6.21"
    kotlinVersion = '1.6.21'
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
```

**#Steps to reproduce  ----------**

```
1. Just clone the repository with git clone git@github.com:RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.ReactNative.git.
2. Go to the folder with cd Rocket.Chat.ReactNative.
3. Customize android packageName
4. Complete the steps of the
https://developer.rocket.chat/open-source-projects/mobile-app/mobile-app-white-labelling
5. Run yarn android-whitelabel packageName
*command example > 
cd android && ./gradlew.bat clean 
yarn start --reset-cache
yarn android-whitelabel packageName
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't link to your code on github. Questions need to be self-contained, so include the relevant code here in the question as a [mcve]. Links can break, or linked content can change, making the question unusable for others with similar problems.